# Which API version is supported by Marketing Cloud Connect?

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, marketing-cloud-connect

Marketing Cloud Connect:
what is the process to follow in order to know what is the API version used in a org?

Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Remember to mark the answer as accepted, if it has been helpful

Answer (score 2):

Currently, as per [this document](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_rn_june_2021_sync_data_api_alignment.htm&type=5), the API version supported since the June 2021 release, is **v51**. Below is copied from the release notes:

**Marketing Cloud Connect API v51 Upgrade**

Journey Builder Integrations and Synchronized Data Extensions now support the latest API version 51, unlocking access to Loyalty Management and Order Management objects for use as the source of events and activities.

**When:** This feature is enabled by a controlled release, which means that the upgrade remains disabled at the time of the main release. After the 232 Marketing Cloud release deployment is complete, every Salesforce org will be upgraded to v51 the week of June 21.

**Who:** This change applies to all Marketing Cloud Connect and Journey Builder customers with the Integrations package enabled.

**How:** After the upgrade, new objects and fields are available to configure in Synchronized Data Sources and Salesforce events and activities.